# Archiving sharepoint site instead of deleting

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a sharepoint site. This contains site nubmer of sites and sub sites collections in it. There are few sites that are created and are not in use. Now my question is how can I find out these old sites and before going deleting it i need to archive it first.

Can any one tell me what is the best possible approach to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could code up a Sitedeleting event handler that backs up and zips the site before deleting it. Another option is a timerjob that locks sites automatically after a certain period of not being used:

[Site deleting event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc706867.aspx) (part of MS's IT governance codeplex project)

[timerjob](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/96bf1f1c-ab6f-43f1-9a5b-a2a8deb60cad/sharepoint--managing-unu.aspx)